# getDuration of a mediaplayer error(1, -107)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my `listView` I am displaying some **media content from an API**. The API does not contain any information about the media duration so I thought I'd make a helper class to deal with this.

```
public static String getPodDuration(String url){
    utils = new Utilities();
    try{
    mep = getInstance();
    mep.reset();
    mep.setDataSource(url);
    mep.prepareAsync();
    mep.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            duration = mep.getDuration();
            Log.i("duration", String.valueOf(duration));
        }
    });
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){

    } catch(IllegalStateException e){

    } catch(IOException e){

    }
    return String.valueOf(utils.milliSecondsToTimer(duration));
}
```

The `getInstance()` is as follows:

```
static MediaPlayer mep = null;
public static MediaPlayer getInstance(){
    if(mep == null){
        mep = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    return mep;
}
```

So with the help of such methods, in main class I pass on the URL of the media file. But for some reason its only giving me 0:00 value. `utils.milliSecondsToTimer(duration)` method works fine though.

I get the following error:

```
error (1, -107)
```

Can someone help implement this ? I do not have to play this media, I simply need to get its duration.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited Response:**

The error `error (1, -107)` is coming from the player engine i.e. `NuPlayer` engine where the player is trying to connect to the `URL`. The error code `-107` is corresponding to `ENOTCONN` (reference: [`errno`](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/errno-module.html)). Please check the connection of the `URL` which you have given to the player.

P.S: Can you please try with a `file` based input?

**OLD Response:**

The error `prepareAsync called in state 8` is indicating that the `MediaPlayer` is in `PREPARED` state and hence, it's an error to invoke a `prepareAsync` in this state. I feel your issue may be due to `reset` being invoked as part of the implementation. Please refer to this [link here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) which explains the differences between newly created and reset player, especially the paragraph below the state diagram.

I would recommend you to modify your get instance implementation to include a `release` and remove the reset as below.I feel this should solve your problem.

```
public static String getPodDuration(String url){
utils = new Utilities();
try{
    mp = getInstance();
    mp.setDataSource(url);
    mp.prepareAsync();
    ........

static MediaPlayer mp = null;
public static MediaPlayer getInstance(){
    if(mp != null){
        mp.release();
    }
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    return mp;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but the implementation freezes the UI and gives me the same output. The reason as to why I am using the reset is that I am to call this method on for several URLs. Please check the edited question. The prepareAsync called in state 8 no longer exists, but I still have the error on mediaplayer (1, -107) ... what is that btw ... i could not find this type of error anywhere.

Comment: @user2247689.. Please check my edited response. Can you please confirm if the input is a streaming input or file based input?

Comment: its a streaming input, for the time being this can only be used with the streaming url input. I did a mediaPlayer implementation with the same URL in a separate fragment, which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting synchronous output from an asynchronous operation. The prepared callback will not have happened by the time the `getPodDuration` method returns, so `duration` will be whatever it was before it entered the method.

Also, you only need to set the prepared listener once. Set it in the same place you create the `MediaPlayer`. Personally, I'm not a fan of the singleton pattern in this case, but it should still work. Your `duration` member will need to be static along with the `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: what would you recommend then ? Instead of using the Singleton pattern, how should I do this now ?

Comment: Is the singleton in a `Service` or an `Activity`? If it's not in a `Service`, that's where I would put it. If it is in a `Service`, it doesn't need to be singleton, just an ordinary member instead (there should only be one instance of the `Service`). I've just found it better to deal with the `MediaPlayer` where the volatile lifecycle of an `Activity` doesn't make the logic overly complicated.